# Formulas that sum or subtract other formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, split

I have the following formulas that sum or subtract other formulas, for example:

```
='Test Sheet'!E2+'Test Sheet'!E3+'Test Sheet'!E4+'Test Sheet'!E5
```

I'd like to write a macro that separates each item and introduces it in the row below. So if the formula above was in cell C1 the result would be:

```
C1: ='Test Sheet'!E2
C2: +'Test Sheet'!E3
C3: +'Test Sheet'!E4
C4: +'Test Sheet'!E5
```

The initial formula could be longer or shorter and include (+ or -).

```
(='Test Sheet'!E2+'Test Sheet'!E3+'Test Sheet'!E4+'Test Sheet'!E5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` a string, like in the following example:

```
Sub test()
Dim a As String
a = "1+2+3"
b = Split(a, "+")
End Sub
```

When looking at the watch Window, `b` looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, no changes on the sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sub.

```
Sub SplitFormula()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
    arr = Split(Sheets("Sheet ABC").Range("C1").Formula, "+")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Sheets("Sheet ABC").Range("C" & 1 + i).Formula = "='Test Sheet'!E" & i + 2
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the sheet named "Test Sheet". Since im working on other sheets lets say "Sheet ABC" refers to "Test Sheet" as well as other sheets. Is there a way to have this affect the formula in "Sheet ABC" regardless of which other sheet the formula refers to? To clarify in "Sheet ABC" i have the formula previously mentioned "='Test Sheet'!E2+'Test Sheet'!E3+'Test Sheet'!E4+'Test Sheet'!E5" but might have similar formulas refering to other sheets as well

Comment: @JROB Then try edited codes.

Comment: Thank you Harun, the issue here i believe is that : "Sheet ABC" and "='Test Sheet' refer to specific sheets . Ss there a way to bypass this ( so i can use it in multiple excels with other sheet names without having to change the code). The idea would be for the macro to split the formula regardless of what the sheet name it is on or the sheet name the formula makes reference to or the cell it is currently on (in this case C1). 
 Basically split it every time it sees a "+" sign Thank you again